# Creating Sperm via cell culture adaptation

Tags: cell-culture, reproductive-biology

I am wondering if it is theoretically possible to create "artificial sperm" via cell culture adaptation. That is at very high level, can you replace the genes of one sperm cell with those of another sperm cell and still have a functioning cell?

An area of application would be male infertility due to "weak sperm". Here you would take a "strong swimmers" from a donor, replace the genes with those from infertile male, and used the cultured adaption in fertilization.

Comment: Are you asking about getting a cell culture to produce sperm cells through cleverness, or about the sperm cloning? From a technical point of view, if you can cut and paste the genome from a sperm to a different cell, it doesn't make a huge amount of sense to put that genome into a different sperm for fertilization. It's a bit like giving your friend some cupcakes by mailing him a brick, then breaking into his house and making the brick/cupcake substitution while he's asleep. Put the genome straight into the egg, why mess around with the extra step?